# Adding to Mac OS X contextual menu Templates like on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: snow-leopard, shortcut-menu, document-management

Does there exist some method to add the `Create document` function to the context menu?
I would love a function like this with the `Templates` folder because I always need to create files with the same template inside and place it in different folders.

Does there exist some app to do this or some `Context menu` modification for `Leopard` or `Lion`?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you could do this.

1. You could use Automator to create new documents through a Service:
   http://pauloppenheim.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/mac-finder-add-new-file-context-menu-item-open-source/
2. Use a context menu plugin, but these are less common on 10.6 and 10.7. You may need to run them using Shortcuts:
   http://www.abracode.com/free/cmworkshop/macosx_10_6_snow_leopard_and_contextual_menu_plugins.html
3. Best of all, in my opinion, you can use a little known OS X feature called Stationary Pad. It's on the Get Info dialog of any file. The way you would go about using it is to create your template file, mark it as a Stationary Pad and then every time you double click it a new copy of that template will be created. Read more:
   http://ignorethecode.net/blog/2009/05/31/creating-new-documents/

[image: Stationary Pad file checkbox]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. If you want to create new files from some template(s), there's no need for a context menu entry. Just mark the template file as "Stationery pad" by opening the file's Info window in Finder (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or menu `File > Get Info`) and [selecting "Stationery pad" in the "General" section](http://www.diigo.com/item/t/4023250_110709254_6363383).

Then, double-clicking that template file will always make a copy of it and open the copy using the default application. You just save the copy under a different name wherever you need it, and your template stays where it was.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this meets the exact requirements of the OP, but it's something I never knew and am grateful to learn - thanks.

Comment: never heard of this, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

## [Neu](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/neu/id405033825?mt=12)

This applications adds "Create Document..." and "Create And Open
Document..." menus to various places, including the **main menubar, the
Dock, and the Services menu that the Finder shows when you right-click**
on something. You can also trigger Neu from any application using a
special key combination.

Neu lets you choose what to make from a list of **templates**, which are simply existing files. Once you've chosen a template, Neu creates a copy of it, brings the Finder to the front, and selects the new file.